# Most efficient way to convert JSONObject to serialized DBObject except using JSON.parse(..)

Tags: java, json, performance, mongodb

I have problem with `com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(..)`. I have a json file which is 800kb, `JSON.parse(..)` is taking nearly 600ms to convert to a serialized `DBObject`.

My question is there any way that we can convert `JSONObject` to a serialized `DBObject` efficiently?

please find the snippet below

```
JSONObject rowObj = rowsArrObj.getJSONObject(i); // Get row object
finalDocument.put(repeatToken, JSON.parse(rowObj.toString()));
```

in the above code `JSON.parse(rowObj.toString())` is consuming the 50% of the process time.

Comment: Did you profile the code and saw what is the most time-consuming part? Also it would be nice to get some details about the structure of the object.

Comment: Yeah @aviad the above line is taking 50% time of the process

Comment: I actually meant: "which part of the class you try to serialize is the most time-consuming?"

Answer (score 0):

DBObject and JSONObject both implement Map, so you can convert one to the other using `other.addAll(one)`. But keep in mind that this might not work well on nested objects.